# How to share objects created from .txt files with other colleagues without sharing the .txt files?

Tags: r, dataframe, share

I have a question that may have a simple answer, but I did not find anything about it.

I have around 30 .txt files located in my working directory, from whom I created 1 list of 3 huge dataframes (each of them with around 6.000.000 rows). These list of 3 dataframes contains the cleaned data which is originally in the .txt files. My question is:

**How could I share this object (list of 3 dataframes) with a colleague so as he can open the same object containing the same data in his computer, without having to send the .txt files, and without having to have a shared working directory?**

I tried with the `dput()` function, but it is not working (I guess it is because of the amount of data).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Save it as an RDS file? It's unclear what you mean by `dput` didn't work

Comment: `save(MY_LIST_OF_DATA_FRAMES, file = "file_to_share.rda")`?  `dput()` creates a code (text) recipe to create an R data object, which is very useful for sharing small examples for code questions, but is an unwieldy and inefficient way to transport data that's any larger.

Comment: Hi Jon, thank you for your answer. For using the save/load option, the document does not have to be kept in the same working directory?

Comment: @JesúsOlivares-Jabalera No, the `file` argument can be a path.

Comment: You may also want check the pins package - https://pins.rstudio.com/